# Attempt to access an unitialized boost::match_result<> class

Tags: c++, boost

The pattern matches any `floating point` number with <= 10 digits before the dot.

```
string pattern = (?<value>([1-9][0-9]{0,9})(,[0-9]+){0,1});
string line = " s - ssd";
boost::regex expr{val_pat};
boost::smatch match;
boost::regex_search(line, match, expr);
if(match["value"].matched){
    cout << match["value"]<<endl;
}
```

This code gives me the

> Attempt to access an unitialized boost::match_result<> class error.

How do I safely extract the named group: value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`boost::regex_search`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) has a post condition of

> If the function returns false, then the effect on parameter m is undefined, otherwise the effects on parameter m are given in the table:

So what you need to do is either capture the return from `regex_search` to make sure it did find something or can can use it as the condition of an if statement like

```
if(boost::regex_search(line, match, expr)){
    if(match["value"].matched){
        cout << match["value"]<<endl;
    }
}
```

If you can use C++11 you can use [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) which will update the match argument even if no matches are found.